# How to properly implement a Matérn kernel function in R?

Tags: r, kernel-trick

This definition is excerpted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function): The Matérn covariance between measurements taken at two points separated by d distance units is given by

$$C_\nu(d) = \sigma^2\frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{d}{\phi}\bigg)^\nu K_\nu\bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{d}{\phi}\bigg),$$

where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, $K_{\nu}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, and $\phi$ and $\nu$ are positive parameters of the covariance.

One can translate the math expression directly into the R code as

```
kernel.matern <- function(d, nu, phi, sigma2) {
  d <- d
  z <- sqrt(2*nu)*d/phi
  return(sigma2 * (z)^nu * besselK(z, nu) / (2^(nu-1)*gamma(nu)))
}
```

However, our first version of `kernel.matern` will return `Inf` at $d=0$. This is because $besselK(z, nu)$ returns 0 at `z=0`. The value $C_\nu(0)$ is actually defined as the limit of $C_\nu(d)$ as $d\to 0^+$. The solution can be adding a small perturbation `eps` to `d`, which gives our second version:

```
kernel.matern <- function(d, nu, phi, sigma2, eps) {
  d <- d + eps
  z <- sqrt(2*nu)*d/phi
  return(sigma2 * (z)^nu * besselK(z, nu) / (2^(nu-1)*gamma(nu)))
}
```

The second version basically solves the problem. One tiny issue left is that the choice of `eps` seems to be quite arbitrary. A large `eps` may give incorrect answer for a small `nu`

```
> kernel.matern(0, 1, 0.07, 1, 1e-6)  # correct
[1] 1
> kernel.matern(0, 1, 0.07, 1, 1e-5)  # biased
[1] 0.9999998
```

while a small `eps` may yield `NaN` for a large `nu`

```
> kernel.matern(0, 20, 0.07, 1, 1e-20)  # NaN
[1] NaN
> kernel.matern(0, 20, 0.07, 1, 1e-15)  # correct
[1] 1
```

My question is, whether can I implement a more robust function for the matern kernel?

(I am also not sure if my question fit cross-validated or should I post it on other communities)

Comment: You could just check for $d = 0$ and return 1, as that is the value of the function unless $\nu = 1$.

Comment: Also, as a general rule it's better to add / subtract the logs of values and exponentiate the final result than to do the multiplication and division directly.   Of course, it may not be an issue on any given problem...

Comment: You'd be better off making `eps` a specified fraction of $\phi/\sqrt{2\nu}$ so it affects the argument of $K_\nu$ directly

Comment: This function is analytic at zero, so just use the first one or two terms of its Taylor series there when the argument is sufficiently small.